# cv2 does not have an attribute 'face'

Tags: python

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Win10x64_Bit\Desktop\Face recognition and identification\src\face-train.py", line 11, in 
recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

using sublime text and I have already tried uninstalling and installing opencv-contrib-pyton, opencv itself as well but the problem still exists

Comment: Have you tried checking the documentation corresponding to you opecv version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced the same issue once, use the below mentioned function and I hope it solves the issue.

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Comment: I had written that before the error occurred. It's after that the error came.

Comment: Can you tell your opencv version ?

Comment: opencv_version = "4.5.5.62"

Comment: As far as I know this function exists in the open cv contrib version, for that, you'll have to uninstall this opencv and install the opencv contrib version. I'm attaching below the contrib version install pip statement 
pip install opencv-contrib-python